# How to retrieve RAM on a 64bit Windows 7

Tags: java, windows, 64-bit, wmi, ram

I have a Java Desktop App installed on a 64bit Windows Vista with 24GB of ram. My program is only finding 4 of the 24GB. I am getting the RAM using

```
wmic computersystem get TotalPhysicalMemory /format:list
```

And if that fails (in case they don't have WMI) I use

```
com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean bean = (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean) java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
long ram = (long) bean.getTotalPhysicalMemorySize();
```

Because I don't have access to the PC I was not able to run tests to confirm which method is used but I am almost certain that the machine does have WMI.

I am suspecting that I am running a 32bit WMI which is likely to have a 4GB limit. How do I run a 64bit WMI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that you're inside a 32-bit JRE on a 64-bit system, you can run the 64-bit WMIC as follows:

```
%SystemRoot%\sysnative\cmd.exe /c wmic computersystem get TotalPhysicalMemory /format:list
```

Note that this command won't work from a 64-bit JRE, or on a 32-bit system, so you need to figure out which environment you're in first.

Comment: I already figured this one out. I am using a similar system: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Windows\\" + (64bit == true ? "sysnative" : "system32") + "\\wbem\\wmic.exe computersystem get ...")` Just never got around to answering me own question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're using a 32-bit JRE instead of 64-bit.  Can we see the output of `java -version`?

Comment: The java is packaged with the program so it is always the same version: `java version "1.6.0_26" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03) Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)`

Comment: You confirmed my suspicion.  Only a 32-bit JRE is being used, which will never be able to see more than 4 GB of RAM.  A 64-bit JRE will look something like this: `java version "1.7.0_01"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_01-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.1-b02, mixed mode)`

Answer (score 2):

Part of the [Windows WOW64 layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64) is to emulate a 32-bit environment *as perfectly as possible.* Otherwise it's a lousy emulator.

WMI for a 32-bit application will only return what a 32-bit application would previously have been able to expect. For example, assuming a program tried to store the number of bytes of system memory using a 32-bit integer. Well, if WMI told the truth and returned 24 GB, then the program would crash trying to stuff that number in a 32-bit integer (or give an incorrect result if the operation isn't checked).

The recommended solution is to use the 64-bit JRE and have your program run in 64-bit.